# multiple sentences in a Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm starting with Lambda Expressions to understand how to define anonymous methods using it.

I have the following simple code:

```
delegate void AddNumber(int number);
class LambdaExpressionSample
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      AddNumber method = r => Console.WriteLine(r + r);Console.Read();
      method(1);
   }
}
```

What I would like is that the method would be equal to this:

```
AddNumber method = new AddNumber(delegate(int number) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(number+number); 
   Console.Read(); 
});
```

But the code with the lambda expression is not working properly because the lambda expression ends apparently with the semicolon ";" after the Console.WriteLine.

How could I make my method execute Console.WriteLine and Console.Read using my lambda example?

Comment: As others have already answered, you just need some curly braces here.

Comment: It is rarely necessary to make delegate types as you have here. If you're using a local variable the 'var' syntax is probably the best way approach. For explicit typing (e.g. a method parameter) I would go with the Func<> and Action<> types. Here you have an action, since there is no return type, so you would say 'Action<int>' instead of 'AddNumber'. Calling this delegate 'AddNumber' implies something about what it does, but there's nothing in the type that makes it mean this. I prefer to let the type describe the signature of the delegate and leave the meaning to the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use braces if you have more then one statement

```
AddNumber method = r => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(r + r);
    Console.Read();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, just remains the ";" after the }

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap the code between curly braces like this:

```
delegate void AddNumber(int number);
class LambdaExpressionSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddNumber method = r =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r + r);
            Console.Read();
        };
        method(1);
    }
}
```

The `Action` encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value. So, to avoid delegate hell with custom delegates everywhere in you code, you should use:

```
Action<int> addNumber;
```

instead of:

```
delegate AddNumber(int number);
```

And the here's your new code with the changes:

```
class LambdaExpressionSample
{
    static Action<int> addNumber;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        this.addNumber = r =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r + r);
            Console.Read();
        };
        this.addNumber(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding curly braces for multiple lines of code solved your problem

```
AddNumber method = r => 
                 {
                       Console.WriteLine(r + r);
                       Console.Read();
                 };
```